# Complex .htaccess redirect from subdirectory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Couldn't find an existing question and answer on this one.

**How can we redirect from this page:**

http://duh.com/candy-apple/123-main-st-OK-48775/1226460/157/

**to this one:**

http://duh.com/details?id=1226460

*Things to know*

- The only part of the URI that is needed is the 7 digit number.  It is always found in the same level of subdirectory in the URI.
- There is no way to know what the string will be in either of the first two subdirectories (/candy-apple/123-main-st-OK-48775/)
- The # of subdirectories will always be the same prior to the 7 digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/(\d+)/.*$ details?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you ever sleep? LOL

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  THANK YOU, anubhava!  (Now, get some sleep!)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this htaccess rule for redirect

**http://duh.com/candy-apple/123-main-st-OK-48775/1226460/157/**

to

**http://duh.com/details?id=1226460**

```
RewriteRule ^candy-apple/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ details?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```